# Master list of labels for traefik that can be used in docker-compose.yml files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tls1.2, traefik

Is there a good master list of labels you can use to customize containers?

I can't seem to find one.

Most configuration documentation tells you how to do configuration in your .toml file but if you want different settings for each backend I often need to set them in the docker-compose.yml file as labels.

I'm specifically looking for how to make individual containers define separate tls configurations for each backend.  Including the entryPoints.https.tls.ClientCA file and optional setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All available labels** are here https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers

Labels are made to define the dynamic configuration.

Because `entryPoints.https.tls.ClientCA` is part of the static configuration, you cannot use labels to set these values.

- https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/basics/#static-trfik-configuration
- https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/basics/#dynamic-trfik-configuration